# saving multiple dygraph plots using htmtools in r

Tags: r, dygraphs

According to this thread: [dygraph in R multiple plots at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502506/dygraph-in-r-multiple-plots-at-once) I have learned how to make multiple chart using `htmltools` package. Now I would like to save the output:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(htmltools)
library(quantmod)#to fetch data
library(lubridate)

getSymbols(c("AAPL","AMZN"))

dyg1 =  dygraph(AAPL[paste(ymd("2015-01-01"),ymd("2020-01-01"),sep = "::"),6]) 
dyg2 =  dygraph(AMZN[paste(ymd("2015-01-01"),ymd("2020-01-01"),sep = "::"),6]) 

jpeg("my_plot_name.jpg")
dy_graphs = list(dyg1,dyg2)
htmltools::browsable(htmltools::tagList(dy_graphs))
dev.off()
```

This code works however saved file is blank (white) jpg file. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you copy your  code in a Markdown Notebook chunck (without dev.off()) : I tried, it works and creates a HTML file with the two graphs.

Comment: Does this post help you? [How to save interactive charts from dygraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094507/how-to-save-interactive-charts-from-dygraph)

Comment: Thank you, I used markdown and it`s good enough.